# Granting Android application the android.permission.INTERNET permission while debugging on device

Tags: android, permissions

I'm very new to Android development and can't find the answer to this.  I have specified that I need the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in my manifest file but when I try to run the app on my phone it gives me a `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent` error.  What am I missing?

Does my app need to be signed before I can request permissions even during development?

Comment: Signing the app would not be a requirement.  It would help to see the code where you invoke the intent and the section of the manifest where you state the permission.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Nick. You probably would have seen the problem straight-off if you'd seen the manifest file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem was I had put the android.permission.INTERNET in the application attributes permission box instead of specifying in the permissions tab (using Eclipse) that my application uses the permission.  The correct line in the manifest is this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

I'm not sure what the application attributes permission is for.

Comment: I have found that, for Ice Cream Sandwich, not only does the permission have to be in its own tag as you pointed out, the application cannot have the attribute "android.permission.INTERNET" at the same time. I had both, and it worked fine on my tablet until I upgraded it from Gingerbread to ICS.