# Socket Programming Support in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, java-native-interface

I have a existing Linux and windows application, in which I use IP_TOS, IPPROTO_IP. Which are belongs to Winsock2.h (in windows) and sys/socket.h (in Linux). But now I am trying to port it into Android. For this reason I want to know is there any such header available that I can use to support my existing application into android.

Edit: Need to mention I have a .so file generate using NDK7. I use JNI to support C++ program from my android application.

Comment: Java supports socket programming, which can very well be used in Android.

Comment: plz specify whats your problem ...

Comment: In my code for both Linux and windows I use IP_TOS and IPPROTO_IP with out specifying any header. But now for android it's getting error. So I think I need to include header that define those two things so that I can get rid of this compilation error.

Comment: What exactly is the compilation error you get?

Comment: Android is based on Linux. I'm not an expert in that but I could imagine the headers exist there, too? Maybe this question helps  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6033581/982149