# Listening on socket under Android with C++ app

Tags: android, c++, sockets, boost-asio

I would need to create C++ console application that runs under non-privileged user under Android 5 (rooted). This application listens on some socket port and accepts connections. It is implemented with `boost::asio`. When application runs as a root, then everything works. When it runs as an ordinary user, then application crashes when it tries to open acceptor:

```
    const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 3784);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ioService);
    acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol()); // Here it throws an exception
```

The exception is a bit confusing but probably it means that I don't have access rights to touch sockets:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
what():  open: Permission denied
Aborted
```

I tried to run application under user `shell` and under user `media`. I also tried to run it under user `u0_a83`, that is assigned to `ProxyDroid` on my device.

I changed `/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml` -- I assigned permission `android.permission.INTERNET` to user `shell` and `media` . I also tried to add group media to `android.permission.INTERNET`, but nothing has helped.

Btw. this is a special case when I really need to implement application in C++ to run under Android. Implementation in Java is not acceptable in my project.

Comment: You have boost working on Android? Why can't you use Java?

Comment: That sounds like quite a challenge! This answer may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033581/using-socket-in-android-ndk

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the best solution is to use users that are predefined in Android and corresponds to capabilities available on the system: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h . In my case I can run the app under user inet (3003) that can create sockets.