# socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP) fail with errno=13(Permission denied)

Tags: android, sockets, linux-kernel, android-ndk, icmp

Run in adb shell, and compiled by NDK.

My code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/netlink.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    printf("sock = %d and errno = %d\n", sock, errno);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
shell@android:/data/local/tmp $ ./poc
sock = -1 and errno = 13
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: Do you have your SELinux in `enforced` or `permissive` mode? Also, what is kernel output after you run your program (`dmesg`)?

Comment: vbox86p:/data/local/tmp # getenforce

Disabled

Comment: dmesg: <6>
    [    8.208501] qtaguid: ctrl_counterset(s 1 10023): insufficient priv from pid=466 tgid=279 uid=1000
    <3>[    9.362826] init: sys_prop: permission denied uid:1003  name:service.bootanim.exit
    <7>[   10.959880] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
    <7>[   20.643991] eth1: no IPv6 routers present

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

It looks like you need to add: -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Possible duplicate of [Using Socket() in Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033581/using-socket-in-android-ndk)

If you're targeting android 7.0, it may be worth looking at the permission changes at https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html but this will depend on whether your targetSdkVersion is greater than **23**